# Creating a constant from properities returned from arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, mapkit

Basically I have two arrays one containing latitudes and the other containing longitudes (the real arrays are much longer obviously).
i.e:

```
latArray = [50.456782, 57.678654]
longArray = [14.578002, 17.890652]
```

I need to go trough these arrays with a for loop and create an object that would have respective latitude and longitude depending in order of the array. However I don't really know how to go about it.
i.e.

```
firstPlace.latitude = 50.456782
firstPlace.longitude = 14.578002

secondPlace.latitude = 57.678654
secondPlace.longitude = 17.890652
```

I need these as separate variables, because I need to pass them into    `MKAnnotation` so that they can be later represented in an `MKAnnotationView` as various locations on the map.

Hopefully this is clear enough, any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Don't use separate arrays, use a custom struct to maintain all parameters of **one** place in **one** instance. The disadvantage of multiple arrays is a out-of-range crash if the number of items are different. *I need these as separate variables*. I'm pretty sure you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would likely be better to use `CLLocationCoordinate2D` from the `CoreLocation` framework to represent a coordinate location.

This sounds like a good place to use the [zip](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip) command.

Here is an example:

```
let latArray = [50.456782, 57.678654]
let longArray = [14.578002, 17.890652]

let coordinates = zip(latArray, longArray).map { lat, lon in
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
}

print(coordinates)
```

Output (tidied slightly):

> [CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50.456781999999997, longitude: 14.578002), CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 57.678654000000002, longitude: 17.890651999999999)]

`MKAnnotation` uses a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` for it's coordinate property anyway, so this should be easier. You could even create your `MKAnnotations` in the map function if you wanted.

Example of using with a struct:

```
let latArray = [50.456782, 57.678654]
let longArray = [14.578002, 17.890652]

struct Place {
    var name: String
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}

let places = zip(latArray, longArray).map { lat, lon in
    Place(name: "Some place",
          coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon))
}

print(places)
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot, I have one additional question, if there was a third parameter (thirdarray) of bools for example, how would I then go about creating a variable with all three properities? i.e.: (latitude: 50.4567819999, longitude: 14.578002, bool: true) ? Would a struct be useful here? 

Thanks if you have time to get back to me with this one.

Comment: I've added an example of how you might use a struct, but zip only works with two arrays. so how you would get the third value would depend on where it comes from. Its best to not use separate arrays if you can. Most apps will likely pull this data from core data or an API and will be in a more structured manner. Then you can serialize it into an object and use it without doing something like the above

Comment: Thanks a million. I will try it this evening.